# regular expression to negate two conditions

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have two regular expressions:

```
".*-.*adm.*"
".*-svc"
```

Could someone explain how I can go about matching all of the strings which don't match/fit the two regular expression above?

Ps. Using vbscript

Comment: Can't you just test to see if `re.test(<pattern>)` is false?

Comment: Right but is there some way to perform the validation in one step, I mean something like (.*-.*adm.*|.*-svc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would ***or*** the two expressions and then use `Not`, like so.

```
Dim re
Set re = new regexp 

re.Pattern = "(.*-.*adm.*)|(.*-svc)"
re.IgnoreCase = true

if Not re.Test(YOUR_STRING) then
    ' Do whatever
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is the tool you're looking for:

```
^(?![^-]*-(?:.*adm|svc)).*
```

Comment: Thanks Alan but looks like this regexp only works on perl and i'm using vbscript.

Comment: Oops! I was assuming VBScript supported the same regex-literal syntax as JavaScript, which was kind of a silly assumption now I think about it.  There were some errors in the regex itself, too.